# Find all optimal solutions with Optimize() from z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

`z3` can solve optimisation problems using `z3.Optimize`. My goal is to apply it in the following way: Given a Boolean formula of propositional logic and a set of constraints, find all models that optimise the constraints, i.e. fulfil as many as possible. My ultimate goal is to select one of these models randomly.

Minimal example: Given the formula `Or(x,y)` and constraints `Not(x)` and `Not(y)`, find the solutions `[x: True, y: False]` and `[x: False, y: True]`.

While `z3.Optimize.model()` prints one optimal solution, it seems to be deterministic and to always print the solution `[x: False, y: True]`:

```py
from z3 import *

x, y = Bools('x y')
s = Optimize()
s.add(Or(x,y))
s.add_soft(Not(x), weight="1")
s.add_soft(Not(y), weight="1")
s.check()
print(s.model())
```

When [`all_smt()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70656700) provided by @alias is applied to this problem, `list(all_smt(s, [x,y]))` outputs:

```py
[[x = False, y = True], [y = False, x = True], [y = True, x = True]]
```

So `all_smt()` finds all solutions, including the non-optimal `[x: True, y: True]`.

What is the best way to find all optimal solutions? Alternatively, is it possible to find an optimal solution in a random way without generating all optimal solutions first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "optimal" in this context. It appears you allow the soft-constraints to be violated, but at least one of them must hold? (After all, (`[x=True, y=True]` is a valid solution, violating both your soft-constraints; which you did allow by explicitly calling `all_smt`.)

Assuming you are indeed looking for solutions that satisfy at least one of the soft-constraints, you should explicitly code that up and assert as a separate predicate. The easiest way to do this would be to use tracker variables:

```py
from z3 import *

def all_smt(s, initial_terms):
    def block_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t != m.eval(t, model_completion=True))
    def fix_term(s, m, t):
        s.add(t == m.eval(t, model_completion=True))
    def all_smt_rec(terms):
        if sat == s.check():
           m = s.model()
           yield m
           for i in range(len(terms)):
               s.push()
               block_term(s, m, terms[i])
               for j in range(i):
                   fix_term(s, m, terms[j])
               yield from all_smt_rec(terms[i:])
               s.pop()
    yield from all_smt_rec(list(initial_terms))

x, y = Bools('x y')
s = Optimize()

s.add(Or(x,y))

p1, p2 = Bools('p1 p2')
s.add(Implies(p1, Not(x)))
s.add(Implies(p2, Not(y)))

asserted = If(p1, 1, 0) + If(p2, 1, 0)
s.add(asserted >= 1)
s.minimize(asserted)

print([[(x, m[x]), (y, m[y])] for m in all_smt(s, [x,y])])
```

Here, we use `p1` and `p2` to track whether the soft-constraints are asserted, and we minimize the number of soft-constraints via the variable `asserted` yet requiring it should at least be 1. When run, the above prints:

```
[[(x, True), (y, False)], [(x, False), (y, True)]]
```

which seems to be what you wanted to achieve in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the imprecision. By “optimal” I indeed meant “minimise violations of soft constraints”.

Comment: No worries. Then the tracker-variable variant is exactly what you want.

Comment: I seem to be getting the correct results by just asserting `asserted = If(Not(x), 1, 0) + If(Not(y), 1, 0)` and not adding the tracker variables at all. Now I'm wondering whether the method can work without the tracker variables, or whether this may have unintended consequences?

Comment: For this particular case, yes; it appears you don't actually need trackers. Tracking variables are a general technique that you can use if you have a solver that doesn't offer optimization; though it can also make coding easier in certain cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70771595/how-to-bias-z3s-python-sat-solving-towards-a-criteria-such-as-preferring-t/70773903#70773903 for a similar problem and further pointers.