# Retracting facts in Z3's datalog engine

Tags: logic, z3, smt

Is it possible to retract facts in Z3's datalog engine? The closest I can find in the documentation is `Z3_fixedpoint_update_rule` which I haven't been able to get to work the way I want.

I have seen other questions deal with retraction using `check-sat-assuming` (e.g. [Incremental SMT solver with ability to drop specific constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356279/incremental-smt-solver-with-ability-to-drop-specific-constraint)) Is there a corollary for the fixedpoint/datalog engine?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.
Once facts are added, rules are pre-processed based on them, other facts are produced, etc, so right now there's no way of going back.
I think only LogicBlox supports such feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One addition, pyDatalog supports retraction.