# Are soft constraints disjunctions?

Tags: z3

In Z3, [soft constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/) can be implemented by placing the actual constraint `P` on the right-hand side of an implication whose left-hand side is a fresh boolean variable, e.g. `assert (=> b1 P)`. Constraints can then be "switched on" per `check-sat` by listing `b`s which are to be considered true, e.g. `(check-sat b1)`.

**Question:** What happens with such constraints `P` if their guard variable `b` is **not** included in a `check-sat`? I assume Z3 treats `b`'s value as unknown, and then branches over the implication/over `b`'s value - is that correct?

**Background:** The background of my question is that I use Z3 in incremental mode (`push`/`pop` blocks), and that I check assertions `P` by `(push)(assert (not P))(check-sat)(pop)`; if the `check-sat` is `unsat` then `P` holds.
I thought about using soft constraints instead, i.e. to replace each such `push`/`pop` block by `(declare-const b_i Int)(assert (=> b_i P))(check-sat b_i)`. Each `b_i` would only be used once. However, if Z3 may branch over all previous `b_j`, then it sounds as if that might potentially slow down Z3 quite a bit - hence my question.

(P.S.: I am aware of [this answer by Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15010748/491216), which says that soft constraints might also reduce performance because certain optimisations might not be applicable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the value of `b1` is not fixed, it will be treated just like any other Boolean.